# Task.Run with async/await inside and await.Task.Run both calling void method

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

What on earth is the difference?

Visual studio says execution of the current method continues because the call is not awaited.

For the first snippet, so i am wondering what is the difference with applying await? is it when you except a result?

I am returning void and it is called via an ajax request using jquery. Are they essentially the same. But one  is when you expect a result?

This is for an asp.net web application that sends requests to an api.

1

```
               Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    
                    await AMethod().ContinueWith(x => x.IsCompleted);

                });
```

2

```
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    
                    await AMethod().ContinueWith(x => x.IsCompleted);

                });
```

3

```
                await Task.Run(() => AMethod().ContinueWith(x => x.IsCompleted));
```

I basically want to understand if they have difference outcomes on the threadpool in terms of performance.

Comment: Are you sure you want to put `ContinueWith` inside the nested task? And it seems you wan't to run it asynchronous, but `await` means "wait for the result of this task, but continue up of this `async` method". If you want to run your task in parallel, simply call `var task = Task.Run(AMethod).ContinueWith(x=> x.IsCompleted)` and call `var result = await task` where you want to wait the result.

Comment: Why would I not use continue with? If i do not have await inside task.run the task does not run. Does async await inside not mean run this on a thread pool thread but await it and let other callers use the thread as well?

Comment: Mec! Error, in the moment you do `Task.Run(AMethod)`, `AMethod` starts in other Thread (you can debug and see subprocesses in VS). But you have to choose if you want to wait until `AMethod` ends or not (using `await` for wait). If your program doesn't depend of AMethod for continue running at all, you'll never notice when AMethod ends, but it runs, and can throw exception and everything. Only if your program needs to wait until AMethod ends you'll see the end.

Comment: It does not run. The api never gets hit without awaiting. My question is more about the threadpool, what difference does it make using await Task.Run() or Task.Run(async etc). Surely they both continue on the current callers thread? What does Mec! Error mean? The request never gets fired if i do not use await

Comment: Surely using await inside task.run is a better approach?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Action_

Comment: that doesnt really answer my question. Can the threadpool run out of threads? at what point and what happens? or does it add new threads?

Comment: Yes, it can run out of threads, but it's so marginal, and you can set ThreadPool.SetMinThreads.

Comment: ok thanks for answering the question. Most requests take a couple of seconds to run, they would be returned to threadpool? What exactly is happening inside snippet 1? A thread from the threadpool of the client application waits until it completes then returns the thread to the threadpool?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'll try to explain what I know (sorry if I have some mistake). The system tries to return the end of the task to the caller thread and continue after await in the caller thread (if you ConfigureAwait(false) it can continue in other different thread, not the caller, be careful with STA and GUI threads and controls). In the first snippet you make a queue in the threadpool to run a piece of code, and that piece of code makes another queue to run AMethod() and (not avoidable) ContinueWith. If everything goes ok, AMethod runs in parallel instantly(both ways use same amount).

Comment: how does the first snippet make 2 queues?

Comment: [`ContinueWith` is a dangerous, low-level method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

Answer (score 2):

1. Starts a new Task. This runs an async method that creates a new Task for `AMethod`, adds a `ContinueWith`, and waits for that result. The outer Task is not awaited.
2. The same except that the outer Task is awaited also.
3. The outer Task is awaited, and the inner Task is also, but the continuation is still on the inner Task.

There is another option you haven't put in:

4. `await Task.Run(AMethod).ContinueWith(x => x.IsCompleted);`
   The outer Task is created directly calling `AMethod` and returning it's Task, and it has a continuation. The resulting Task is awaited.

All of these tasks run on the caller's thread in a GUI application, unless `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used. They are run via callbacks, and the big question is not what that does to the threadpool, but how you propose to deal with exceptions without `await` to unwrap them.

Comment: What difference does this have on the threadpool? in terms of performance?

Comment: Have edited. There is no effect either way, it's the same amount of threads.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.

Comment: *"3. The outer Task is awaited, but the inner Task is not"* <== actually the `Task.Run` method undestands async delegates, and awaits their result. The `ContinueWith` returns a `Task`, so the delegate is asynchronous, so it is awaited. You can read more about this here: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Fixed

Answer (score 1):

> i am wondering what is the difference with applying await? is it when you except a result?

No. It's when you want to asynchronously "pause" the current method until the called method is complete.

To be clear, you *almost always* want to do this on ASP.NET, because request-extrinsic code is dangerous. What the first code snippet is doing is called [fire and forget](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html), and it's not doing it in a safe way at all.

Side notes:

1. Don't use `ContinueWith`; use `await` instead. `ContinueWith` is a low-level, dangerous method.
2. Avoid `Task.Run` on ASP.NET. It can interfere with ASP.NET's usage of the thread pool, and provides no actual benefit to your code.

The proper code to use is:

```
var result = await AMethod();
_ = result.IsCompleted;
```

Comment: its perfectly fine. i do want to fire and forget.

Comment: i do not want the client to stall while the request is being processed. so i am using ajax as well. Why is ContinueWith dangerous? How does Task.Run interfere with the threadpool anymore than await Task.Run does?

Comment: I am using await inside Task.Run whats the difference?

Comment: It is designed this way to work as a distrubuted system.

Comment: What is a safe way to fire and forget?

Comment: @BobHoskins regarding fire-and-forget on ASP.NET, you should read [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html "Fire and Forget on ASP.NET") article. I bet that after reading it, the idea of fire-and-forgetting will become mush less enticing. In short a forgotten task may never run, and you may never know that it didn't run.

Comment: @BobHoskins the `ContinueWith` is "dangerous" in the sense that its behavior cannot be determined by examining the code it contains and its calling site. You must also know the ambient `TaskScheduler.Current`, because this is what will run the continuation by default. If you know nothing about `TaskScheduler`s and use the `ContinueWith`, you are essentially not in control of your program. If you **do** know very well about `TaskScheduler`s, then you **can** use safely the `ContinueWith` by configuring it appropriately. But even the experts avoid it, because the `await` is much easier to use.

Comment: @BobHoskins: "What is a safe way to fire and forget?" I just so happen to be writing [a blog post series](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) on that topic right now.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias its just returns if the task is completed which is fine because it has an await attached to the request inside. I think you are over thinking the problem. Its fine

Comment: @StephenCleary I understand what you are saying, but it works fine, the api recycles every 2000 minutes, and no job lasts longer than 50 minutes.  It works and seems to be reliable. I want to fire and forget a http request to an api. Does that not make sense? I do not want to wait for the result. I am not looking for perfection just want the app to fire a request then return to the user interface. thats it

Comment: I have ran long jobs and ran short jobs while the large job was running, everything worked fine.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias surely using await with it counteracts the problem?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias i want to use the threadpool, from what i can see makes no difference at all, just nitpicking, i agree the easiest option is always the best but it does not mean there is an issue. ill keep you posted